# Weird React behavior on Android (Mobile) when browser app is closed and reopened. (Async axios calls not running sometimes?)

Tags: android, reactjs, express, cookies, redux

So I am building a full stack (Express and React) app that uses backend cookies for authentication and what not. The issue I am having is on Android I am getting weird behavior; and maybe on any mobile device. Here is an example of the code:

```
// React App.js

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  const checkIfLogged = async () => {
     console.log('[CHECKIFLOGGED]')
     try {
        const user = await axios.get('/user/route/', {withCredentials: true})
        setAuth(true)
        setUser(user.data)
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
     }
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
     checkIfLogged();
  })

  return(
   <>
     {components example, not real code}
   </>
  )
}
```

So in this example once the App is mounted the useEffect() calls checkIfLogged(), which makes an axios request to the backend and if the right cookie is present the user is returned and set into the state. And also 'auth' state is set to true. And that state variable could control conditional components for example.

So here is the issue. In the desktop browser this runs great! No problems! State is set up correctly; every time the page loads or refreshes checkIfLogged() runs. On Android in the mobile browser the State is unpredictable kinda. If I open the website on my Android browser, then close the browser from my Androids recents (so a full swipe away close) then reopen my browser; the site loads in like a weird kinda cache fast load way. And when that happens the await axios.get() will sometimes run and sometimes not run. But even if the axios.get() doesn't "run" the setAuth(true) setUser(user.data) after it will still execute as if the axios call passed... even though it was never sent. And I am using morgan on the backend to watch all http requests and the axios.get doesn't go through. It's super annoying... and this website I am building is mostly for myself to be viewed mostly on Android... but I can't seem to find a solution and there is like no information on it around the web.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think I solved this issue; I changed useLayEffect to useEffect; that was actually a typo anyways. And then in my index.js I set the service worker to "unregistered". I think the serviceworker was caching HTTP requests for offline use; which is what I don't want.